# Rotating labels in feyn

Tags: feynmp-auto

Is there any way to rotate labels in feynmp? I want the dots in this picture to run from k_1 to k_n, so I need to rotate the labels by about 80 degrees clockwise. Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,aps,12pt,eqsecnum]{revtex4}  
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  
\linespread{1}    
\usepackage{slashed}      
\usepackage{simplewick}    
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{gensymb}     
\begin{document}     

\begin{fmffile}{graph41}    
   \begin{fmfgraph*}(120,120)    
    \fmfcmd{input vbloboval;}    
    \fmfleftn{i}{9}    
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
    \fmfblobOval{0.16w}{v1}    
    \fmf{fermion}{o1,v1}    
    \fmf{fermion,label=$p'$}{v1,i7}    
    \fmffreeze    
    \fmf{photon}{v1,i1}    
    \fmf{photon}{v1,i2}    
    \fmf{photon}{v1,i3}    
    \fmfv{label=$k_1$}{i3}    
    \fmfv{label=$\cdots$}{i2}    
    \fmfv{label=$k_n$}{i1}    
    \end{fmfgraph*}     
 \end{fmffile}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to play with the angles and labels a bit, but this shows how to use `\rotatebox` to achieve a rotated label.

For those not familiar with `feynmp` protocol, one must first `pdflatex` the file; then `mpost graph41.mp`; and finally `pdflatex` it again.

EDITED to attempt to lower labels into alignment, though the algorithm of `fmfgraph` seems to want to restrict the label relocation somewhat. REEDITED to use `\rule` as the label-realignment mechanism.

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,aps,12pt,eqsecnum]{revtex4}  
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  
\linespread{1}    
\usepackage{slashed}      
\usepackage{simplewick}    
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\begin{document}     

\begin{fmffile}{graph41}    
   \begin{fmfgraph*}(120,120)    
%    \fmfcmd{input vbloboval;}    
    \fmfleftn{i}{9}    
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
%    \fmfblobOval{0.16w}{v1}    
    \fmf{fermion}{o1,v1}    
    \fmf{fermion,label=$p'$}{v1,i7}    
    \fmffreeze    
    \fmf{photon}{v1,i1}    
    \fmf{photon}{v1,i2}    
    \fmf{photon}{v1,i3}    
    \fmfv{label=\rotatebox{-65}{\rule{0pt}{10pt}{$k_1$}}}{i3}    
    \fmfv{label=\rotatebox{-70}{\rule{0pt}{7pt}{$\cdots$}}}{i2}    
    \fmfv{label=\rotatebox{-65}{$k_n$}}{i1}    
    \end{fmfgraph*}     
 \end{fmffile}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to shift the labels upwards/downwards or left/right? I tried: 

    \fmfv{label=\rotatebox{-70}{\raisebox{50pt}{$\cdots$}}}{i2}  

but it didn't have any effect

Comment: @supercoolphysicist Please see my revision.  I improved the label alignment with some vertical motion prior to the rotate, but the `fmfgraph` seems to want to resist the relocation.  A `\raisebox` (which would have been the logical choice) seemed to have no effect.

Comment: @supercoolphysicist I simplified the revision to use `\rule` and it seems to work OK.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would ideally like the k_1 and k_n labels to remain upright, something along the lines of:
 
    \fmfv{label=$k_1$}{i3}    
    \fmfv{label=\rule{0pt}{-20pt}{\rotatebox{-70}{$\cdots$}}}      {i2}     
    \fmfv{label=$k_n$}{i1}

(Sorry I can't get that to display correctly, but basically I only want to adjust the dots)

Comment: @supercoolphysicist maybe something like `\fmfv{label=\rule{0pt}{8pt}$k_1~~$}{i3}\fmfv{label=\rotatebox{-70}{$\cdots\phantom{~\cdots}$}}{i2}\fmfv{label=$k_n~$}{i1}`?  In any event, controlling the placement is a royal pain.

Comment: Did you mean to put the ~ in the phantom argument? It doesn't work for me either with or without the ~, it only recognises \phan and then "tom" is coloured in green as if it is text